# 'method' object is not subscriptable problem in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

in my code I am trying to make a guessing game, i take input from what num do you want to start to what num do you want to stop

and that the code which break(that code in a while loop):

[image]

```
''' 
   while True:
   user = int(randrange[num1 , num2])
'''
```

Comment: Please add the rest of your code with correct formatting, otherwise it's very hard to help you out in any way.

Comment: read the doc about `random.randrange`, the error message tells you exactly what you try to do and that is not possible in python and makes no sense at all, a callable is not subscriptable

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `[]` when you should be using `()`.
Also, there is no need to cast the result to an integer since it will already be an integer.

Fixed code:

```
user = randrange(num1 , num2)
```

`()` are used to call a function while `[]` are used to retrieve an index. Since randrange is a function, `()` must be used and `[]` will cause the crash.